# Kafka Java Consumer already closed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have just started using Kafka. I am facing a small issue with the consumer. I have written a consumer in Java.

I get this exception - IllegalStateException This consumer has already been closed.

I get exception on the following line :

```
ConsumerRecords<String,String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(1000);
```

This started happening after my consumer crashed with some exception and when I tried running it again it gave me this exception.

Here is the complete code :

```
package StreamApplicationsTest;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

import java.util.*;

public class StreamAppConsumer {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int i = 0;
    //List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> topics = Collections.singletonList("test_topic");
    //topics.add("test_topic");
    Properties consumerConfigurations = new Properties();
    consumerConfigurations.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
    consumerConfigurations.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    consumerConfigurations.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    consumerConfigurations.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"TestId");

    Consumer<String,String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerConfigurations);
    consumer.subscribe(topics);

    while(true){
        ConsumerRecords<String,String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(1000);
        Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String,String>> iterator = consumerRecords.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            i++;
            ConsumerRecord<String,String> consumerRecord = iterator.next();
            String key = consumerRecord.key();
            String value = consumerRecord.value();
            if(key=="exit" || value=="exit")
                break;
            System.out.println("Key="+key+"\tValue="+value);
        }

        System.out.println("Messages processed = "+Integer.toString(i));
        consumer.close();

    }
}
}
```

I am just stuck with this issue any sort of help will be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening  because you are closing the consumer at the end of your infinite loop so when it polls a second time the consumer has been closed. To handle the immediate problem I'd wrap the entire `while(true)` loop in a try-catch and handle the consumer close in the catch or finally block.

However if different shutdown signals aren't handled carefully with a Kafka consumer you run the risk of losing data. I'd recommend looking at Confluent's example for graceful consumer shutdown [here](https://github.com/gwenshap/kafka-examples/blob/master/SimpleMovingAvg/src/main/java/com/shapira/examples/newconsumer/simplemovingavg/SimpleMovingAvgNewConsumer.java). In your case since you're running in the main thread it'd look something like this ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    //List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> topics = Collections.singletonList("test_topic");
    //topics.add("test_topic");
    Properties consumerConfigurations = new Properties();
    consumerConfigurations.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    consumerConfigurations.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    consumerConfigurations.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    consumerConfigurations.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "TestId");

    Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerConfigurations);
    consumer.subscribe(topics);

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
    {
      public void run() {
        consumer.wakeup();
      }
    });

    try {
      while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(1000);
        Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> iterator = consumerRecords.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          i++;
          ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = iterator.next();
          String key = consumerRecord.key();
          String value = consumerRecord.value();
          if (key == "exit" || value == "exit")
            break;
          System.out.println("Key=" + key + "\tValue=" + value);
        }
        System.out.println("Messages processed = " + Integer.toString(i));
      }
    } catch (WakeupExection e) {
      // Do Nothing
    } finally {
      consumer.close();
    }
  }
}
```

basically running `consumer.wakeup()` is the only threadsafe method in the consumer so it's the only one than can be ran inside of Java's shutdown hook. Since the consumer is not asleep when wakeup is called it trips the wakeupexection which falls through to gracefully shutting down the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
        topics.add("test.topic");

        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "IP_TO_KAFKA_SERVER");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(topics);

        System.out.println("Polling");
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(5000);

        try {
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : consumerRecords) {
                System.out.println(record.offset() + ": " + record.value());
            }
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }
```

Make sure your server or local kafka is reachable

Output

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ MVN ---
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Polling
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
6: test
7: tes
```