# java.lang.IllegalStateException: This consumer has already been closed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Set up kafka consumer with this configuration

```
kafkaconfig:
  acks: 1
  autoCommit: true
  bootstrapServers: example.com:9092
  topic: item
  groupId: EWok-group
  keyDeserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  valueDeserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  maxPollRecords: 1
  pollMillisTime: 15
  retries: 5
  heartBeatInterval: 300
  sessionTimeout: 100000
  maxPollInterval: 30000
```

code

```
 while (true) {
            try {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = eWokIntegrationConsumer.poll(Duration.of(kafkaCommConfig.getPollMillisTime(), ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
                if (!consumerRecords.isEmpty()) {
                    LOG.info("Consumed Record Count: {}", consumerRecords.count());
                    consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
                        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
                        eWokMessageProcessor.onMessage(record.value());
                        eWokIntegrationConsumer.commitSync();
                    });
                } else {
                    LOG.info("Polling returned without any records.");
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                LOG.error("Consumer was interrupted. But still continue to poll. Exception:", exception);
                eWokIntegrationConsumer.close();
            }
        }
```

10000 ms is taking for processing the data which we have received from kafka consumer.but getting 
exception saying

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This consumer has already been closed.

Exception Logs

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This consumer has already been closed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquireAndEnsureOpen(KafkaConsumer.java:2202)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1332)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1298)
```

Kafka version : kafka-clients-2.0.1

Could you pls suggest any one how should configurations Kafka consume looks like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka Java Consumer already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123557/kafka-java-consumer-already-closed)

Comment: This is exactly like duplicate to tagged question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123557/kafka-java-consumer-already-closed

Comment: This is not a duplicate questions.I didn't closed the consumer in while loop but I closed the consumer only when if exception will raise.

Comment: Why not place catch outside of loop and then close the consumer? @user6903099

Answer (score 0):

I have put System.exit(0) in other place in the source code.That is why consumer has leave the group and mark as closed.

I have remove System.exit(0) from source code.Now it's working fine.